# Is there a way to re execute the postconstract init methode after an action?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

i have a datatable that is populated from DB with init function that has postconstruct annotaion, the probleme is that when i delete a row in the table the table data doesnt change even thought that instance is actually deleted from the DB so i was wondering if i could execute the init function again so it brings the new data from DB and put them in the datTable using ajax maybe.

```js
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Compte implements Serializable{

 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -7177239517089845251L;
 
 private int id_compte;
 private int id_agence;
 private int id_client;
 private String num_compte;
 private double solde;
 private String date_creation_compte;
 public ArrayList<Compte> comptes;
 
 dao d = new dao();
 
 public Compte() {
  super();
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 
 @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
  
  ExternalContext ec =
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(false);
  if(session.getAttribute("idagence")!=null){
   comptes=d.getComptesAgc((String)session.getAttribute("login"));
  }else{
  comptes=d.getComptes((String)session.getAttribute("login"));}
    }
```

```html
 <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">
         <ui:param name="titre" value="Liste de Comptes"/>
         <ui:define name="content">
        
            <ice:form id="form">
            <style type="text/css">
                .ui-datatable-odd {
                    background-color:lightgray !important;
                    background-position-y: -1400px; 
                }
            </style>
   <ace:dataTable id="cptTable" value="#{compte.comptes}"
    var="cpt" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10">
        ...
        </ace:dataTable>
```

Comment: the solution is to perform an update of your dataTable, not to `brings the new data from DB and put them in the datTable using ajax`

Comment: uhhmmmm by calling the postConstruct annotated method?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend placing the code that you use to populate your datatable into it's own method so that it can be called when necessary by your @PostConstruct, action method, and/or Ajax method.

Comment: Yes, but if the code the OP wants to call IS the full postconstruct annotated method, that would be overkill

Comment: Thus I wouldn't recommend calling the full @PostConstruct method from another method.

Comment: Care to explain why? What the dangers are? Cause I don't see any risks/dangers/problems and then we'd have two competing (opinionated) answers and that is not what StackOverflow is about... opinions... it is about exact, specific (one thruth) answers

Comment: You should be treating your `@PostConstruct` like a second constructor. It exists because when the bean executes your constructor it doesn't have access to any dependency injections. When it's done dealing with your constructor it will inject any dependencies and then execute your `@PostConstruct` method so that will have access to it.

For the same reason it wouldn't make sense to call your constructor from another method in the same class, it wouldn't make too much sense to call `@PostConstruct` method from another method. It's about clearly defining the purpose of the method.